# Hide component through return output

Tags: angular

I have a structure where I have a parent component, it loads an array for example from 1 to 5.
With this array I loop and create new child components by passing a parameter.
Each child gets this parameter through @Input and does a processing, and depending on the result I need to hide this component.

I tried to use @Output but as I set the same output for all children so if a return that should be hidden ends up hiding all children.

Follow my code

Dad

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of listtest">
    <app-split-grouping [idWallet]="item" [document]="document" 
      (hideChildren)="hidecomponent = true"
      *ngIf="hidecomponent" class="col-5 pt-4 pb-4 alert alert-secondary"> 
    </app-split-grouping>
</ng-container>
```

Children

```
export class SplitGroupingComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() idWallet: number;
@Input() document: string;
@Output() hideChildren = new EventEmitter();
.
.
.
if (this.splitGrouping.Status !== 'FOUND') {
    this.hideChildren .emit(this);
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have `hidecomponent = true` you're always making/giving hidecomponent `true`. So it will never change. You have to compare it with the current item/childcomponent item returned after the child component finish processing. `this.hideChildren.emit(this)` should be `this.hideChildren.emit(idWallet);`, the current item returned to tell Dad: "No, Dad, I didn't find it. I'm going to hide from you now".

Try this:

In Children:

```
@Output() hideChildren = new EventEmitter<number>()

if (this.splitGrouping.Status !== 'FOUND') {
    this.hideChildren.emit(idWallet);
}
```

In Dad's template:

```
<app-split-grouping [idWallet]="item" [document]="document" (hideChildren)="hideComponent($event)" *ngIf="item === hideItem" class="col-5 pt-4 pb-4 alert alert-secondary">
</app-split-grouping>
```

In Dad's component:

```
hideItem?: number;

hideComponent(event: number) {
  this.hideItem = event;
}
```

By the way, if you prefer not to have:

```
hideItem?: number
```

you can do to start:

```
hideItem: number | undefined = undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hiding all of your children because they are sharing the same variable `hidecomponent`.

You can modify your code to use `item.hidecomponent` if adding a property to the item isn't an issue.

However it seems like a bad practice to have the processing done inside the component, you may want to consider extracting whatever method is determining whether to show or hide the component and run it from the parent:

```
listtest.forEach(item => myservice.checkItem(item).subscribe(result => {
    item.hidecomponent = result
});
```

Comment: What would be the best model? Because each item must make a request in a WebApi and one cannot depend on the other. Imagine I have a screen where I will upload products, but each product I need to go to the supplier's webapi to search for information such as value, description, etc. I need to carry the products asynchronously, without one product locking the other. So I thought of this model I created, would you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can move the request logic inside a service, inject it in your parent component and call it from here while looping over your products by passing each one of them as argument. HTTP calls are asynchronous so they shouldn't lock each other.

Comment: Got a basic model of this? Because currently the logic is in services but imagine that I have an array from 1 to 3 and need to call the service 3 times, passing 1, then 2 and then 3, the return of each service need to inject into the component. How do I do that ? Sorry for the basic questions and thanks for your patience.

Comment: Added a short snippet of code as an example. You will probably need to adapt to your needs but it should give you an idea.